# How to completely turn off camera on mediastream javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, peerjs

im trying to create a video conference web app..

the problem is im trying to disable my camera on the middle conference, its work but my laptop camera indicator still on (the light is on) but on my web, video show blank screen, is that normal or i miss something?

here what i try

```
videoAction() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
  }).then(stream => {
     this.myStream = stream
  })

  this.myStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = !(this.myStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled)
  this.mediaStatus.video = this.myStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled
}
```

Comment: This may come down to webcam drivers.  It may be that, if some program has the ability to toggle camera visibility, the cam's light turns on.  Have you tried with any other cameras?

Comment: not try, but the light will off when i close the tab, so i think no problem with drivers..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is also a [`stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop) method which should do the trick in Chrome and Safari. Firefox should already mark the camera as unused by setting the `enabled` property.

```
this.myStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

Comment: its work, but i cant reenabled it with `this.myStream.getVideoTracks()[0].start();`

Comment: No, that's not possible. But in Chrome and Safari which require this workaround it is possible to call `getUserMedia()` again without triggering another user prompt.

Answer (score 6):

We need to assign `window.localStream = stream;` inside navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia method

For Stop Webcam and LED light off.

`localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();`
 `video.src = '';`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, [MediaStreamTrack.enabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/enabled) is a Boolean, so you can simply assign the value `false`.
To simplify your code, you might call:

```
var vidTrack = myStream.getVideoTracks();
vidTrack.forEach(track => track.enabled = false);
```

When `MediaStreamTrack.enabled = false`, the track passes empty frames to the stream, which is why black video is sent. The camera/source itself is not stopped-- I believe the webcam light will turn off on Mac devices, but perhaps not on Windows etc.

`.stop()`, on the other hand, completely stops the track and tells the source it is no longer needed. If the source is only connected to this track, the source itself will completely stop. Calling `.stop()` will definitely turn off the camera and webcam light, but you won't be able to turn it back on in your stream instance (since its video track was destroyed). Therefore, completely turning off the camera is not what you want to do; just stick to `.enabled =  false` to temporarily disable video and `.enabled = true` to turn it back on.

Comment: if just use .enabled=false, then users will lose trust to the app, cause webcam light still on. it's not good approach