# How to implement camera toggle like Google Meet

Tags: webrtc, html5-video, video-capture, google-meet

I am trying to implement something like the camera on/off toggle that Google Meet has. I have tried getting the tracks from getUserMedia and setting enabled = true/false, it works but the camera indicator light is still on all the time. How are they able to toggle the camera and the indicator light?

Comment: There is a bug in Chrome (which I assume the Meet team is aware of) and Safari. You can call `stop()` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64012898/how-to-completely-turn-off-camera-on-mediastream-javascript/64013564#64013564

Answer (score 1):

To lose the camera indicator you will have to remove any reference to the stream (no just set enabled to false).
So you have to remove the track from the peer.
Thanks to [Transceiver APi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpTransceiver) you can easily switch/remove track from the peer without renegotiate the ice.